# Как убрать предупреждение "Сборка My.dll неверно указана как файл"?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

Библиотеки подключаемые не через NuGet, сложили в папку dll в каталоге проекта. Добавили ссылки на них, всё работает, но при построении в Visual Studio в *Списке ошибок* выдаётся предупреждение

> Сборка "dll\My.dll" неверно указана как файл.

Что от меня хочет MsBuild и как избавиться от предупреждения?

---

фрагменты .csproj:

```
<Reference Include="My">
  <HintPath>dll\My.dll</HintPath>
</Reference>
...
...
<Content Include="dll\My.dll" />
```

Comment: Не могли бы вы добавить фрагменты из .csproj файла, где упоминается имя этой сборки? Желательно все упоминания (поиском можно найти).

Comment: @Uranus, готово

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
<Content Include="dll\My.dll" />
```

Эта строчка говорит о том, что этому файлу в свойстве `Build Action` указано `Content`. [Описание ошибки в MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228157.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) никак не связано с значением BuildAction=Content которое я нашел в [этом ответе](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/145752/what-are-the-various-build-action-settings-in-visual-studio-project-properties).

#### Описание ошибки

> MSB3178: Assembly '' is incorrectly specified as a file.
>
> This warning is generated during application manifest generation when the build process detects that a file reference is actually a (managed or native) assembly.

*Это предупреждение выдается если в процессе сборки обнаружена ссылка на файл который на самом деле является управляемой сборкой или нативной библиотекой.*

#### Описание значения `Build Action=Content`

> Content: Allows you to retrieve a file (in the same directory as the assembly) as a stream via `Application.GetContentStream(URI)`. For this method to work, it needs a `AssemblyAssociatedContentFile` custom attribute which Visual Studio graciously adds when you mark a file as "Content"

*Добавляет возможность получить содержимое файла в виде потока с помощью метода `Application.GetContentStream(URI)`. Файл должен быть помещен в той же папке что и текущая сборка.*

---

Тем не менее, [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/436471/vs2005-assembly-assembly-is-incorrectly-specified-as-a-file) можно найти ответ, который рекомендует для решения аналогичной проблемы изменить `Build Action` на `None`. Это не принятый ответ, но у него самое большое количество плюсов.

Я не сумел воспроизвести аналогичную ошибку и проверить ответ. Но нашел подтвержение ему в [этом блоге](https://chocosmith.wordpress.com/2008/07/02/assembly-is-incorrectly-specified-as-a-file/).

> This time I tried something else, this time I set the build action to none and copy if newer for each of the dll’s generating this warning.
>
> It seems to have gotten rid of the warnings plus the program still compiles and runs (with complete directory clean).

*На этот раз я попробовал кое-что еще. Я установил build action в none и задал опцию copy if newer для каждой dll, которая выдавала это предупреждение.*

*Кажется, это помогло избавиться от предупреждений, плюс программу можно было скомпилировать и запустить.*

---

Поэтому я советую попробовать установить свойство `Build Action=None`. Скорее всего это поможет решить проблему.

Так как у меня нет локализованного интерфейса студии, прикладываю скриншот, на тот случай если будущим читателям будет необходима подсказка - как найти это свойство в студии. Нужно выделить файл в Solution Explorer (Обозреватель решений), и тогда его свойства станут доступны в этом окне.

[image]

Comment: Вроде бы помогло, спасибо. `Build Action` = `Действия при сборке`

Comment: `Content Include` заменился на `None Include`