# Задать путь для DLL файла копируемого локально

Tags: c#, visual-studio, dll, компиляция

Нужно задать локальную папку для DLL файлов которые по умолчанию копируются в папку **Release**, нужно **Release\моя папка**. Указать вложенный каталог относительно компилируемого **EXE файла**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Опция **Copy Local (Копировать локально)** в свойствах ссылки на сборку не позволяет задать имя папки, в которую желательно скопировать сборку. Сборка всегда помещается в **Output path** проекта.

Можно поступить следующим образом. Добавить папку **MyFolder** в самом проекте, и поместить в нее необходимые сборки просто как файлы. Если задать опцию **Copy to Output Directory** у этих файлов как **Copy always**, то при сборке проекта они будут копироваться в **Output path** вместе с **MyFolder**.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

> Опция **Build Action** для файлов по умолчанию устанавливается в **Content**. Это обычно не приводит к проблемам, но [лучше поменять на **None**](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/871739).

Теперь необходимо установить опцию **Copy Local** у ссылки на эту сборку в **false**, чтобы она не копировалась в *Output path**. Скорее всего, ссылка после этого станет невалидной. Это потому, что у нее не задан корректно **Hint Path**. Чтобы не править **csproj** файл вручную, удалите ссылку и добавьте ее заново используя раздел **Browse** в **Reference Manager**.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Если теперь удалить все лишние сборки из **Output path**, то при запуске приложения будет возникать `FileNotFoundException`, потому что CLR не знает откуда теперь их загружать. Необходимо указать что **MyFolder** содержит необходимые приложению сборки через атрибут [`<probing>`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/configure-apps/file-schema/runtime/probing-element) в конфигурационном файле (**App.config**, если в проекте его нет, просто добавьте).

```
<runtime>
  <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
    <probing privatePath="MyFolder" />
  </assemblyBinding>
</runtime>
```

---

Если это ссылка не на обычную сборку, а на другой проект в том же самом решении, необходимо в этом другом проекте изменить **Output path** таким образом, чтобы новая версия сборки автоматически копировалась в **MyFolder**. Таким образом, при изменениях в другом проекте приложение не будет продолжать использовать старую версию сборки. Нужно использовать относительный путь, чтобы настройки не сломались при переносе проекта на другую машину. Две точки означают переход на одну директорию выше.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2):

Свойства проекта > вкладка Build > Output path

Задать путь можно отдельно для каждой конфигурации: Debug, Release.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

Вероятно, вам нужно, чтобы сборки могли загружаться не из папки по умолчанию. Путь к ней задаётся в элементе [probing](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/configure-apps/file-schema/runtime/probing-element) конфига.

Подробнее смотрите [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/125031/184217).

Comment: Ответ неверный, мне нужно не всю сборку а только отдельные файлы DLL поместить в отдельную папку в том-же каталоге где расположен компилируемый файл Release\ .exe   а для Dll Release\Папка путь к которой нужно указать

Comment: @SergeyUsick - Ну так помещайте. | Для _заданного_ вопроса ответ правильный. Но я вас понял, сейчас дополню ответ.

Comment: на вашем скрине разрешён небезопасный код!

Comment: @SergeyUsick - В моём проекте небезопасный код используется, поэтому он разрешён. Вам не нужен - не тыкайте галки вслепую. Красным цветом выделено важное. Верите, нет - мне похрен, кто там что впервые открыл.